# Ask permission from the user to write files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, file-io

I have a web application that has the feature to upload PDF which is done by the following process:

1. Create a folder on user's local path ( `C:/resource/pdf/` )
2. Write the PDF file inside the folder.

On my local(running on eclipse/tomcat) it can write the files directly but on the web I actually getting an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\resource\pdf\Daily News.pdf (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
...
```

I'm using Spring MVC if it is related.

**Is there a way to ask the user for a permission to write files in their local?**

Comment: This is rather obvious `Permission denied`, please check the permission, and I do not think this folder is `user local path`

Comment: Where can I check that? I uploaded my web app at [CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) if it is related.

Comment: check if that folder is writable for other user, right click on this folder and check `permission` tab

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15zs7ign5v43qoa/test.png) is the permission. The code creates that folder. Is there a way to set that up for me to write files there?

Comment: in xp, it is called `security` tab. can you create this file in your server path?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit noob, but I create this folder through my codes. And I'm failing to create it because of the permission. The one I showed you is the folder created when I run the web application locally ( on my eclipse not from the web host )

Comment: you could try to create a folder or file by your application to see whether you have the permission, either eclipse or web is acceptable.  actually I do not think windows have such a restricted permission control.

Comment: If you can't create and use the folder in your home directory; then, you will have to contact your hosting provider to find out what your options are.

Comment: You're trying to  write files **on the server** to a directory you don't have permission to write to. There's no "user" to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you use a `File` object in your code; if so you can just do this:

```
File folder;
// set directory and everything
// create folder
folder.setWritable(true, true);
```

Then you can check if you can write with this:

```
write = folder.canWrite();
System.out.println(write);
```